# Let $F$ be a field, show that $(A \setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C\; \forall A, B, C$ in $F$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let F be a field, Show that:
$$(A \setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C,$$

$\forall A, B, C \in F$

where \ indicates set minus.

I've started with left hand side and reached this point:

$$(A \cap C^c) \cap (B \cap C^c)^c$$

where ^c is the complement.
I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Having used De Morgan's law I get to: (C ∪ A) ∩ (C ∪ C^c) ∩ B^c Having also done the distributivity over U (Maybe wrongly)

Comment: What does $\setminus$ mean for elements of general _fields_?

Comment: This question is either a duplicate or is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use De Morgan's law $(X \cap Y)^c = X^c \cup Y^c$, and then use distributivity over $\cup$.

Let me know if you need another shove in the right direction.

Comment: Having used De Morgan's law I get to:
(C ∪ A) ∩ (C ∪ C^c) ∩ B^c
Having also done the distributivity over U (Maybe wrongly)

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to translate from the set level to the element level, and then simplify using logic: starting at the most complex left hand side, we have for any $\;x\;$,
\begin{align}
& x \in (A \setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$, three times"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x\in C) \;\land\; \lnot(x \in B \land \lnot(x \in C)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: use $\;\lnot(x \in C)\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x\in C) \;\land\; \lnot(x \in B \land \text{true}) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify; reorder in the order of our goal"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x\in B) \;\land\; \lnot(x \in C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$, twice"} \\
& x \in (A \setminus B) \setminus C \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality, this proves the original statement.